# the simple way to check if the elements of a list or set are single type?

Tags: python

i need to write a piece of code if all the elements are int or all are string then return true,else return false

```
[1,'1','a','b'] False
[1,2,3,4] True
['apple','orange','melon'] True
['1', 2, 3, 4] False
```

my solution is these

```
def foo(l):
    t = type(l[0])
    if t is not str and t is not int:
        return False
    for x in l:
        if t != type(x):
            return False
    return True
```

i think it should be better.

Comment: Your lists all contain strings

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN: The second one doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type(l[0]) in [int, str] and all( type(e) == type(l[0]) for e in l)
```

Answer (score 11):

This code checks generally if all elements are of the same type:

```
len(set(type(elem) for elem in elems)) == 1
```

It answers the title of your question, but works differently than your solution (which returns false for a list of floats).

Comment: This erroneously returns `True` for `elems = [[], []]`, doesn't it?

Comment: @hayden On my system (cPython 3.2), I get `True`, although the OP asks  if everything is a string or an int.

Comment: @phihag - his code works for int/str, but the title is more general.

Comment: i don't think it would be best solution, it you determined the type is different you could return ,you don't have to check all element

Comment: That's right, this problem is made for short-circuiting (cf. my answer :-)).

Answer (score 3):

If you require all your elements in list `l` to be of a certain type, e.g. `int`, then the following is a very efficient method:

```
any(not isinstance(e, int) for e in l)
```

It short-circuits, i.e. on the *first* occurrence of a list element that is not if type `int` it evaluates to `False`.

If you require all your elements in list `l` to just be of the same type and do not provide this type as input information there is at least one element in the list, then this a is the analogon:

```
all(type(e) == type(l[0])) for e in l)
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `all` (rather than any not). Also, you could test against `type(l[0])` rather than `int` (to cover the case of strings).

Comment: Yes, in order to generalize this method, testing against the first elements type would be useful.

Comment: +1 for using `isinstance` rather than checking type equality.

Comment: @lvc: depending on the requirements, it could be that an `isinstance` check is not what we want. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403231/python-can-isinstancei-typei-evaluate-to-false

Answer (score 1):

```
def all_of(iterable, types=[str,int])
    actual_types = set(map(type, iterable))
    return len(actual_types) == 1 and next(iter(actual_types)) in types
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [32]: len(set(map(type, [1, 2, 3]))) == 1
Out[32]: True

In [33]: len(set(map(type, [1, 2, '3']))) == 1
Out[33]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that the sequence is all of a specific type...

```
def check_all_same_type(sequence, typ, strict=True):
    if strict:
        return all(type(item) == typ for item in sequence)
    return all(isinstance(item, typ) for item in sequence)
```

If you just wanted to make sure they're all the same type...

```
types = set(type(item) for item in sequence)
all_same = (len(types) == 1)
if all_same:
    print "They're all a type of", type(next(iter(types)))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it will be faster:

for `ints`:

```
>>> ints = set(list(range(10)))
>>> ints
set([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>>
>>>
>>>
>>> l = set([1,2,3,'d'])
>>> l - ints
set(['d'])
>>>
>>> l = set([1,2,'3','d'])
>>> l - ints
set(['3', 'd'])
>>>
```

it possible to use this method for `str's`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might do it. After the initial conditions are checked the function will stop checking as soon as an elem's type fails to pass. It also handles empty lists.

```
def check_elem_types(l):
    return bool(l) and type(l[0]) in (int, str) and all(type(e) == type(l[0]) for e in l[1:])
```

If you wanted to handle unicode strings (in Python 2.x), you would instead need this:

```
def check_elem_types(l):
    return (bool(l) and isinstance(l[0], (int, basestring)) and
            all(type(e) == type(l[0]) for e in l[1:]))
```