# Python: can isinstance(i, type(i)) evaluate to False?

Tags: python, oop, built-in

I am looking for `something` in the following piece of code so that the `isinstance()` check afterwards evaluates to `True` in any case:

```
i = WonderfulClass()
classinfo_of_i = something(i)
isinstance(i, classinfo_of_i) # must evaluate to True
```

If `type` is your answer, I'd be grateful if you explained why. Is `type` the real counterpart of `isinstance`? Or, asked the other way round, can you think of a case where `isinstance(i, type(i))` evaluates to False?

This question arose in the context of [the simple way to check if the elements of a list or set are single type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402845/the-simple-way-to-check-if-the-elements-of-a-list-or-set-are-single-type/12402930#12402930), where we have to go through a sequence and check if all the sequence elements are of the same kind. In this context, elements will be compared to each other. This comparison could be based on `type` or based on `isinstance`.

Relevant [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance) regarding `isinstance(object, classinfo)`:

> Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo
>   argument

Comment: @KennyTM: I have, yes, but I believe that `type` is not the counterpart of `isinstance` for any case. I am looking for a solution that makes the test evaluate to True in any case.

Comment: Is there any case you need to consider `isinstance(i, type(i))` to be false?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? (I.E., why do you need `isinstance...` to be `True` as opposed to other ways of checking the class (`type`) of `WonderfulClass()`?)

Comment: What do you mean by "classinfo"? `type()` returns the class

Comment: @gnibbler: I got this term from the Python documentation (as quoted). I see where the focus of this question moves to and will edit it.

Comment: To conclude from all your answers: `type` and `isinstance` both compare the type object. Furthermore, `isinstance` goes up the chain of inheritance if the type objects do not match in the first place. Therefore, if I want to be sure that the to entities I am comparing are of the same type -- without considering parent classes -- I should test for ``type(i) == type(u)`` while ensuring to only use newstyle classes. Right?

Comment: "I believe that type is not the counterpart of isinstance for any case." You believe, but have you produced a counterexample?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: You are right, I was not able to come up with one. However, I did not trust myself, that's why I asked. Everything is clarified now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *"Is type the real counterpart of isinstance? Or, asked the other way round, can you think of a case where isinstance(i, type(i)) evaluates to False?"*

I can't see any situation where `isinstance(i, type(i))` would not return `True`.

`type()` inspects and returns the type object from an instance so there's no reason why the returned value would fail the `isinstance()` check.

Digging into the source of cPython, we see that the [code behind `type()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9b40d018e4cf/Objects/abstract.c#l31) simply returns the type object attached to the instance:

```
v = (PyObject *)o->ob_type;
Py_INCREF(v);
return v;
```

while the first thing that the [isintance() code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9b40d018e4cf/Objects/abstract.c#l2521) does is check if the types match exactly (it would later move on to match against classes in the chain of inheritance):

```
int
PyObject_IsInstance(PyObject *inst, PyObject *cls)
{
   _Py_IDENTIFIER(__instancecheck__);
   PyObject *checker;

   /* Quick test for an exact match */
   if (Py_TYPE(inst) == (PyTypeObject *)cls)
      return 1;
```

Note that `Py_TYPE` is simply a macro that returns `obj->ob_type` which matches the return value of `type()`. This is [defined in Include/object.h](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/9b40d018e4cf/Include/object.h#l117) as:

```
#define Py_TYPE(ob) (((PyObject*)(ob))->ob_type)
```

Comment: You answered what I was mainly after: the implementation differences between `type()` and `isinstance()`. Thanks for the insights.

Answer (score 2):

`type()` returns what is expected, but only if you use new style classes (inherit from `object`).

Consider the following:

```
>>> class WonderfulClass(object):
...     pass
...
>>> i = WonderfulClass()
>>> isinstance(i,type(i))
True
>>> type(i)
<class '__main__.WonderfulClass'>
>>> class AnotherClass:
...     pass
...
>>> z = AnotherClass()
>>> type(z)
<type 'instance'>
>>> isinstance(z,type(z))
True
```

So although the `isinstance` check will work, its worth noting the differences.

Comment: My question was a bit diverse. I am sorry, I would love to accept multiple answers here, because they all answer parts of my question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `isinstance` is meant to deal with inheritance. E.g.

```
>>> isinstance("asdfs", object)
True
```

Here a string was considered an instance of object, as "str" type is a heir of "object" type. So type is not a strict counterpart to isinstance.

Everything is an object in python, so, isinstance(anything, object) should return True for anything and, thus, all the values in your array have a common ancestor in their class hierarchy: object.

If you'd like to directly refer to a more special type/store it in a variable and be able to compare to it, `types` module might be of interest to you.

Comment: Also this is an important answer to my (confused) question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class P:
...   pass
...
>>> p = P()
>>> type(p)
<type 'instance'>
>>> p.__class__
<class __main__.P at 0x015A6A78>

>>> class D(object):
...   pass
...
>>>
>>> d = D()
>>> type(d)
<class '__main__.D'>
>>> d.__class__
<class '__main__.D'>
```